# Coffeescript functions not workin

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am new to coffeescript but I am trying to have several things occur when I click on my webpage.

The problem is, I cannot figure out how to get more than 4 events to occur.  This is the code i have now:

```
ready: ->
$("#titleDD").click ->
  $("#titleDD").css('border', '3px solid #D0D0D0');
$("#catDD").click ->
  $("#catDD").css('border', '3px solid #D0D0D0');
$("#titleDD").click ->
  $("#catDD").text("hellow world");
$("#catDD").click ->
  $("#titleDD").css('border', '1px solid #D0D0D0');
$("#titleDD").click ->
  $("#catDD").css('border', '1px solid #D0D0D0');
```

As is, it will change the border and update the text.  However, the last line doesnt work.  catDD's border will not go back to 1px when I click on titleDD.  Does anyone know why?  If i switch the order of the code, it is always the first 4 clicks that work and the fifth click doesnt.

I have tried to make another ready: -> statement but that makes it so nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unite statements under 2 handlers instead of many for the same CSS selectors:

```
ready: ->

$("#titleDD").click ->
  $("#titleDD").css('border', '3px solid #D0D0D0');
  $("#catDD").css('border', '1px solid #D0D0D0');
  $("#catDD").text("hellow world");

$("#catDD").click ->
  $("#catDD").css('border', '3px solid #D0D0D0');
  $("#titleDD").css('border', '1px solid #D0D0D0');
```

Comment: i just tried this and clicking on titleDD has the correct outcome, however nothing happens when i click on catDD

Comment: my indentation was off, this works perfectly, thank you!